# Retrofit encode URL

Tags: android, retrofit

Como faço para minha url que contem um "+" ser enviada pelo retrofit com "encode" porem atualmente a url resultado é:

```
http://api.xxxx.com.br/aluno?campo=220+2d+
```

E dai meu backend entede este + como um espaço, oque me gera vários problemas.

O resultado de url que quero é este:

```
    http://api.xxxx.com.br/aluno?campo=220%2B2d%2B
```

Oque tentei agora foi adicionar encode como true no querymap porem mesmo assim, nada muda:

```
    Call<JsonElement> updatealuno(@QueryMap(encoded = true) Map<String, String> campospraupdate);
```

Comment: Utilize `URLEncoder` ao adicionar o valor em `campospraupdate`

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado